# passing variables to os.chdir in python

Tags: python

I'm having an extremely frustrating experience attempting to change directories in python using variables within the program. Specifically, suppose I have:

```
index = '999'
os.environ['dir_name'] = 'Directory_Name_' + index
os.chdir('$dir_name')
```

gives OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '$dir_name'

and yet

```
 os.system('echo $dir_name')
```

returns 'Directory_Name_999' (a valid directory name)
and similarly

```
   os.chdir('Directory_Name_999')
```

changes the directory without error.
Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Try `os.chdir(os.environ['dir_name'])`, or `os.system('cd $dir_name')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing what `os.system` can do and what Python can do. `os.system` understands that `$dir_name` is a variable named `dir_name`. It checks its environment variables and finds it.

Python has no idea what `"$dir_name"` is, and assumes you're using a literal string. It tries to change the directory to that, and fails since there is no literal directory `"$dir_name"`.

Instead, do:

```
index = '999'
os.environ['dir_name'] = "Directory_Name_"+index
os.chdir(os.environ['dir_name'])
```

You could also have `os.system` change your directory, since it knows what `"$dir_name"` means:

```
os.system('cd $dir_name')
```

But why muck with system calls? Just have Python do it.

Answer (score -1):

For others looking for the same thing you can do this:

```
index = '999'
dir_name = "Directory_Name_"+index
os.chdir(dir_name)
```

Hope this helps.